# How can I parse signed_request from facebook graph api in django 1.7

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook sends a POST request to access a custom tab in a page and that request comes with a parameter `signed_request` which is encoded.

I tried to use this code to decode it:

```
def base64_url_decode(inp):
    padding_factor = (4 - len(inp) % 4) % 4
    inp += "="*padding_factor
    return base64.b64decode(unicode(inp).translate(dict(zip(map(ord, u'-_'),
                                                        u'+/'))))


def parse_signed_request(signed_request, secret):

    l = signed_request.split('.', 2)
    encoded_sig = l[0]
    payload = l[1]

    sig = base64_url_decode(encoded_sig)
    data = json.loads(base64_url_decode(payload))

    if data.get('algorithm').upper() != 'HMAC-SHA256':
        print('Unknown algorithm')
        return None
    else:
        expected_sig = hmac.new(secret, msg=payload, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()

    if sig != expected_sig:
        return None
    else:
        print('valid signed request received..')
        return data
```

It is not working for me. Just returns `None`.

How to fix this? or is there any other way to decode the signed_request?

Comment: See if you get the `data` variable filled correctly. If so, then this is just a problem with checking the signature (and that could be due to f.e. the wrong app secret being used.)

Comment: Stupid me! For some stupid reason, I used the SECRET_KEY environment variable instead of APP secret key. Now it is wokring :) thank you very much ))